# Search view : MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web, view, asp.net-mvc-controller

I need to make a "Search and filter view"

My problem:

I want to create a Search view where the user selects by which attribute he wants to search and than enters something in textbox and submits it. The view than goes to controller finds what it needs to find and displays it

My view goes into the part that is written for when the `HttpPost` function in controller is done. But it goes in early. I have trouble displaying my results here's controller code part:

```
public ActionResult Filter()
{
    return View();
}


[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Filter(string option, string search, FormCollection fc)
{
    var bll = new STUDIJSKIPROGRAMBLLProvider();
    StudijskiProgramViewModel model = new StudijskiProgramViewModel();

    if (option == "skracenicaSmjer")
    { 
        // For now I just putted some random number to get some data displayed

        var program = bll.Fetch(2004);
        model.StudijskiProgram = program;
        return View(model);
    }
    else if (option == "skracenicaProfil")
    {
        return View();
    }
    else
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

And View Code:

```
@model SolutionC.Models.StudijskiProgramViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Pretraga studijskih programa";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Filter", "StudijskiProgram", FormMethod.Get))
{
    <h2>Pretraga studijskih programa</h2>

    <b> Kriteriji pretrage: </b>

    <input type="radio" name="prvi" value="prvi1"/> <text>Skraćenica profil</text> 

    @Html.RadioButton("option", "skracenicaSmjer") <text>Skraćenica smjer</text>

    @Html.RadioButton("option", "skracenicaProfil") <text> Skraćenica profil </text>

    @Html.RadioButton("option", "ECTSOpterecenje")<text>ECTS</text> 

    @Html.TextBox("search") 

    <input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "Traži" />  

}
@using (Html.BeginForm("Filter", "StudijskiProgram", FormMethod.Post)) 
//Don't want my view to display this until i click Submit and my controller sets up data for display
{
<table class="table table-striped">
        <thead class="alert alert-info">
            <tr>
                <th>
                   Naziv smjera:
                </th>
                <th>
                    Naziv profila:
                </th>
                <th>
                    Šifra:
                </th>



            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tr>
            <td> @Model.StudijskiProgram.smjer </td>  //Compilation fails here
            <td> @Model.StudijskiProgram.profil</td>
            <td> @Model.StudijskiProgram.IDStudProg </td>
        </tr>
</table>
}
```

Comment: You dont have 2 forms, and you don' need a POST method, just the GET method with parameters with `string option, string search`. There is a lot of code here which makes no sense so hard to understand what you want to display in the view. You need to show you models. And are you expecting to display just one item in the table, or many?

Comment: Just one yes, wil try it with one method and post back

Answer (score 0):

You got it all wrong.

`@using (Html.BeginForm("Filter", "StudijskiProgram", FormMethod.Post))`

Only means "Make me a form tag wrapper with the following attributes` **not** only show this when button is posted.

You should instead wrap it with a condition, that will only be met when the model property is set.

```
if (Model.SomeProperty)
{
    <table class="table table-striped">
    ...
}
```

The `bool SomePropery` should be declared on your Model and be set to **true** when you want the post section to appear.

Note: You should return `View(model)` when wanting the View to **know** your model.

Comment: I still can't get it to show some other data after submit 1) on load ->http://www.deviantpics.com/sky
2) Here I enter something in textbox and after submit the page will look like Image 1) ... http://www.deviantpics.com/skF..but I need it to show something else..something user searched for. Typed 2004 inside controller code will change it to user input later after I get it to show something else at least....here's the view code now http://www.deviantpics.com/images/2016/06/12/3.jpg